# javascript code not working within oninput attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to integrate the code for price range slider in one of my new project but I don't know why the javascript code written for the slider not running.

I tried to integrate the code and I noticed some others related answers in which the solution were just the changing of version from html 4 to 5 but  I am using html 5. I googled a lot but didn't get any solution.

The code which I am trying to integrate is here which is working fantastically on this link https://codepen.io/glitchworker/pen/XVdKqj  but not on the local file.

The sliders doesn't move. They just remain still at 30 and 60 position.

```css
body { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; color: #888; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; }

/***** Top menu *****/

.navbar {
background: #444;
-o-transition: all .6s; -moz-transition: all .6s; -webkit-transition: all .6s; -ms-transition: all .6s; transition: all .6s;
backface-visibility: hidden;
  align-content: left;
}


[slider] {
  position: relative;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 45px 0 10px 0;
}

[slider] > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 14px;
}

[slider] > div > [inverse-left] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0 7px;
}

[slider] > div > [inverse-right] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0 7px;
}

[slider] > div > [range] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
}

[slider] > div > [thumb] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
}

[slider] > input[type=range] {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 14px;
  top: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: transparent;
  border: transparent;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: red;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: red;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: red;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
}

div[slider] > input[type=range]::-ms-tooltip {
  display: none;
}

[slider] > div > [sign] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -11px;
  top: -39px;
  z-index:3;
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
  color: #fff;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

[slider] > div > [sign]:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 16px;
  top: 19px;
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  border-top-width: 16px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #1ABC9C;
}

[slider] > div > [sign] > span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 28px;
}

[slider]:hover > div > [sign] {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div slider id="slider-distance">
  <div>
    <div inverse-left style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div inverse-right style="width:70%;"></div>
    <div range style="left:30%;right:40%;"></div>
    <span thumb style="left:30%;"></span>
    <span thumb style="left:60%;"></span>
    <div sign style="left:30%;">
      <span id="value">30</span>
    </div>
    <div sign style="left:60%;">
      <span id="value">60</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="range" tabindex="0" value="30" max="100" min="0" step="1" oninput="
      this.value=Math.min(this.value,this.parentNode.childNodes[5].value-1);
      var value=(100/(parseInt(this.max)-parseInt(this.min)))*parseInt(this.value)-(100/(parseInt(this.max)-parseInt(this.min)))*parseInt(this.min);
      var children = this.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes;
      children[1].style.width=value+'%';
      children[5].style.left=value+'%';
      children[7].style.left=value+'%';children[11].style.left=value+'%';
      children[11].childNodes[1].innerHTML=this.value;" />

  <input type="range" tabindex="0" value="60" max="100" min="0" step="1" oninput="
      this.value=Math.max(this.value,this.parentNode.childNodes[3].value-(-1));
      var value=(100/(parseInt(this.max)-parseInt(this.min)))*parseInt(this.value)-(100/(parseInt(this.max)-parseInt(this.min)))*parseInt(this.min);
      var children = this.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes;
      children[3].style.width=(100-value)+'%';
      children[5].style.right=(100-value)+'%';
      children[9].style.left=value+'%';children[13].style.left=value+'%';
      children[13].childNodes[1].innerHTML=this.value;" />
</div>
```

[image: Here is the navbar]

Comment: Correct the title.

Comment: If you're getting my point then I don't think there is need of editing. Can you describe the answer?

Comment: What is expected behaviour? And why have all code inline?

Comment: Never heard `oninput`. You mean `onchange`?

Comment: @MarkusZeller Nope. [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) - it handles paste too

Comment: @mplungjan using it in navbar

Comment: What you have there and in the pen seems to work once I made a snippet out of it. What is the problem you experience and when?

Comment: @mplungjan delete the javascript code written in oninput attribute. The sliders won't move. I am getting this problem while I run the whole code in local html file

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking. Please provide something that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @NguyenYou wait. I am going to add navbar code.